# How can I get username/password in basic authorization using nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

Is there any function getting username/password nginx.conf in basic authorization?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume no way. You can get Authorization header value, but extracting username and password from it actually means MD5 reverse lookup.

Comment: I see. I'll do this in application. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can use standard variable **$remote_user** wich means *user name supplied with the Basic authentication*.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user

Answer (score 2):

with nginx 3rd-party module [FRiCKLE/ngx_coolkit](https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_coolkit), you can use `$remote_passwd` to get password. and nginx core has `$remote_user` .