# Parse HTTP Basic Authorization Header in NGINX

Tags: nginx

Can Nginx natively parse the Authorization header (base 64) and return the username password?  Or is a custom Lua function required to do this?

**Example Request**

```
curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://example.com

> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Comment: No, as far as I know, it can't be done natively. If you are using OpenResty, check [`set_decode_base64`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_decode_base64) function (the `set-misc-nginx-module` is a part of OpenResty bundle).

Comment: The username is available as a variable, but not the password.

Comment: As Richard says the username will be available if you use `auth_basic` and you'll get `$remote_user`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851434